# cfsavecontent passing variables dynamically

Tags: coldfusion

I have a cfm page with html and css, needed for an email template. I have a sender.cfm file, which will include the template file and dynamically replace variables in the template file.

Below is a part of the template file

```
 <td valign="top" align="left" style="padding:0 0 10px 0;">                 
    <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:18px; margin:8px 10px 10px 0; padding:0; color:#102044;">
        [INSERT QUESTION 1]
    </p>  
 </td>
```

Now in the sender file, I have a cfquery which is fetching the questions. I am doing something like this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="questions">
    <cfoutput><strong>#get_ques_text.questiontext#</strong></cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>  

<cfinclude template="weekly_template.cfm">

<cfset nl_template = replaceNoCase(nl_template, "[INSERT EMAIL TITLE]"
                        , "WEEKLY EMAIL") />

<cfset nl_template = replaceNoCase(nl_template, "[INSERT QUESTION 1]"
                        , questions)/>
```

I want to be able to get the list of all the questions in the `cfsavecontent` variable. However, in the code above, I am only getting the first one. Any ideas why?

Comment: you're not looping through anything, you need to loop through your query

Answer (score 2):

If you reference a query value just as `queryName.columnName`, then you are referencing one of:

- the first row's value for that column;
- the entire column, as an array;

depending on the context. In the context you're doing so - where CF is expecting a string - you'll just be getting the first row's value for that column.

If you want to iterate over the whole query, you need to *tell* ColdFusion that, via:

```
<cfloop query="yourQuery">
```

In your case, something like this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="questions">
    <cfloop query="get_ques_text">
        <cfoutput><strong>#questiontext#</strong></cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Comment: Better yet, use cfoutput to loop through the query.  You need a cfoutput tag to get its contents anyway.

Comment: @DanBracuk using `<cfoutput>` to loop sounds good at first, but it'll burn you later 'cause it doesn't support nesting.

Comment: I'm a firm believer in "clean code": CFOUTPUT says "stuff gets output", CFLOOP says "I'm looping". It's just slightly better. And makes no difference to the compiled code, for all intents and purposes.

Comment: If you insist on cfloop, you should at least put the cfoutput tags outside the loop.

Comment: @DanBracuk as per last week: please stick to only offering advice when you have an informed position. Cheers.